# can't revert to older version of node, can't uninstall node, OSX

Tags: node.js, uninstallation

Have installed node 0.12.2, but need to revert to 0.10.33 to run the applications I need to.
I have tried installing 0.10.33 and switching versions using

```
set 0.10.33 to default with 'nvm alias default 0.10.33'
```

But node runs previous version (0.12.2) when started again.

I have tried uninstalling node via various methods, but each one has been blocked:

```
uninstall node
```

"You must be in root to run this tool"

(I am the only user (with Admin access) on my machine 
I tried

```
cd /
```

then

```
uninstall node
```

But still got 
    "You must be in root to run this tool"

Tried

```
sudo uninstall node
```

"Uninstall Failed...
Reason: ErrorMissingBundle"

I may have installed node with Homebrew - it was a while back, can't quite remember. So tried:

```
brew uninstall node
```

"Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node"

Other information I can give:

```
which node
```

/usr/local/bin/node

I see node and npm in
/usr/local/bin

Any help most appreciated - I'm not a command line expert, and fairly new at Node.

Answer (score 2):

To switch from different node.js version with nvm just use `nvm use 0.10.33`

Comment: OK, I have removed 0.12.2, and have 0.10.33 installed at the following  location by nvm.
    /Users/matthewwilliams/.nvm/v0.10.33/bin/node

However I still need to switch to 0.10.33 manually because when I start a bash and type "which node", no version is found.
I understand i need to move node from my nvm directory in user directory to another location for default use, but I don't know the commands. What should I do here? Can someone please give me the commands to move this. Thanks.

Comment: nope, you have to run nvm use 0.10 everytime for your user, put it in your bash_profile.
If you want to install it for all user, you must run `NVM_DIR=/usr/local/nvm curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.25.4/install.sh | bash`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be using NVM (node version manager). If you are you can install different versions using

```
nvm install version_no
```

and then you can switch versions using the command

```
nvm use version_no
```

If you have not used NVM to install node you can uninstall node using the instructions in this answer - [How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x).
Then if you need different versions of node I would recommend using NVM, which allows you to install and use different versions of node on the same system. https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: Have tried most things here, I wonder if it might be something to do with paths. 

0.10.33 is here: 
/Users/matthewwilliams/.nvm/v0.10.33/bin/node

    0.12.2 is here: /usr/local/bin/node

Comment: I can switch versions, but it's not holding switched version as default

This might also help explain problem:
I hope a new bash, type 
    node --version and get v0.12.2

I run 
    . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

then nvm uninstall 0.12.2

it tells me version is not installed

Comment: Okay your path for each node should be the same. The looks like you have both node and nvm installed. If your using nvm you should only use `nvm install version` to install node and not other methods. I would use the link above to remove node and maybe even nvm and start again....

Comment: On another note what happens when you type `nvm use 0.10.33`?

Comment: I will try the remove and reinstall. I think the problem was different Node versions installed via different ways.
I can switch versions using    nvm use 0.10.33 but when i stop and restart, 0.10.33 is lost.

Comment: @mattw what do you mean when you stop and start? If you mean your local machine, then yes, this is intentional. When you start you just type in `nvm use version` and it loads up the version of node you want, so you are only making changes in the node environment that you want. Its a bit like a python virtual environment, a bit.